# Convert multiple array into a string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->get(array('id'));
return $est_data;
```

result:

```
[{"id":43},{"id":71},{"id":41},{"id":39}]
```

This is my above laravel condition and result, i want the result to be like `43,71,41,39`.
Can anyone please help me, how can be this done using php. i tried with `implode()` function, but getting error, please help...thank you

Comment: did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array?

Comment: Welcome. "_but getting error_" What would that error be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: $est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->get(array('id'));

   
   return $implode = implode(' ',$est_data);  Showing error, invalid argument passed

Comment: In pluck its getting only first single value, but not getting all...thank you '

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? The pluck behaviour you're describing was changed ages ago

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2 version

Comment: In laravel 4.2 `lists` achieves the same result that `pluck` achieves in version 5+ so you can use `lists('id')` to get only the ids

Comment: thank you soo much, it worked. using lists(id), i got only id numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel `pluck` method will select required fields only:

```
$est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->pluck('id');
return $est_data;
```

As commented by @apokryfos for your laravel version (4.2) `lists` method should be used, so it is:

```
$est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->lists('id');
return $est_data;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought `pluck` is only supported in `QueryBuilder` not `EloquentBuilder`. Just checked, both supports `pluck`

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments `pluck` was called `lists` in laravel 4.2 and confusingly laravel 4.2 also had a function called `pluck` which is now called `value` so the logic here is sound but the question should have had the correct laravel version mentioned

Comment: Updated answer to include @apokryfos comment about naming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the laravel [array_flatten()](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#arrays) array helper:

> The array_flatten function flattens a multi-dimensional array into a
>   single level array:

```
$array = array('name' => 'Joe', 'languages' => array('PHP', 'Ruby'));

$array = array_flatten($array);

// array('Joe', 'PHP', 'Ruby');
```

In your case:

```
$est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->pluck('id');
return array_flatten($est_data);
```

Comment: Thank u, i tried with the same as u told, but Still i am getting the same result as [{"id":43},{"id":71},{"id":41},{"id":39}]

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = implode(',',$est_data[0]);
```

This will solve your problem. You should read about [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)(convert to string) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (string to array). They are really useful php functions.

Reading your comment, your error is coming from the fact that you try to access `$set_data` and not `$set_data[0]` where you values are based on the output you provided us.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [php array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function, specifying the `id`:

```
$est_data = Establishments::where('status',0)->where('city','=',$data['location'])->pluck('id');
return array_column("id", $est_data);
```